# Find string within string using Regex in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, find

I have following string.

```
dim str=
 "tblIDs = ExecuteSPReader("USP_testSP", GENRL.MakeArrayList("ID", "2", "TypeID", 30))"
```

Now I want to find string like `"USP"`using regex expression. Can anyone tell me the regex to find out this string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `@"(?<=ExecuteSPReader\("")[^""]*"`

Comment: Worth looking on this link . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369543/using-vb-net-and-regex-to-find-string-inside-nested-string

Comment: If you'd paste in more examples we could refine the pattern

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Dim result As String = Regex.Match(str,"(?<=ExecuteSPReader\("")[^_]+").Value
```

Effectivly means: look behind `ExecuteSPReader("` and find continous characters that are not `_`